# How to add a callback to ipc renderer send

Tags: javascript, electron

Googling says you can add a callback to it, but the documentation just says "arg1, arg2, arg3" etc.

They also have sendSync, but I'd prefer not to block while my event is being sent [we're trying to do as much work through the browser as possible, because writing client code in node, seems a little daft].

If the creators have a sendSync, then surely they have a version with callbacks, or better yet promises.

Some examples of things i'd like to be able to do:

```
//callback
ipcRenderer.send('anaction', '[1, 2, 3]', function() { console.log('done anaction') });
//promise
ipcRenderer.send('anaction', '[1, 2, 3]')
    .then(function() { console.log('done anaction') });

//sync exists, but it blocks. I'm looking for a non-blocking function
ipcRenderer.sendSync('anacount', '[1, 2, 3]')
console.log('done anaction');
```

Comment: I'm so angry... why the hell doesn't the electron documentation mention that send returns a promise...

Comment: Oh, you can return anything on the receiving end... I get it now.

Comment: Have you checked the ipc async method found [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md#sending-messages)

Comment: No I missed that. Thanks for alternative!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In case anybody is still looking for an answer to this question in 2020, a better way to handle replying from the main thread back to the renderer is not to use `send` at all, but rather to use [`ipcMain.handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) and [`ipcRenderer.invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args), which make use of `async`/`await` and return Promises:

**main.js**

```
import { ipcMain } from 'electron';

ipcMain.handle('an-action', async (event, arg) => {
    // do stuff
    await awaitableProcess();
    return "foo";
}
```

**renderer.js**

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

(async () => {
    const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('an-action', [1, 2, 3]);
    console.log(result); // prints "foo"
})();
```

---

`ipcMain.handle` and `ipcRenderer.invoke` are compatible with [`contextBridge`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#contextbridge), allowing you to expose an API to ask the main thread for data from the renderer thread and do something with it once it comes back.

**main.js**

```
import { ipcMain, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';

ipcMain.handle('an-action', async (event, arg) => {
    // do stuff
    await awaitableProcess();
    return "foo";
}

new BrowserWindow({
    ...
    webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: true,
        preload: "preload.js" // MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY if you're using webpack
    }
    ...
});
```

**preload.js**

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from 'electron';

// Adds an object 'api' to the global window object:
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    doAction: arg => ipcRenderer.invoke('an-action', arg)
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
(async () => {
    const response = await window.api.doAction([1,2,3]);
    console.log(response); // we now have the response from the main thread without exposing
                           // ipcRenderer, leaving the app less vulnerable to attack    
})();
```

Comment: In doAction I suppose you don't need extra async/await

Comment: @norekhov I believe you are correct! Edited :)

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to unseen_damage for this suggestion.
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md#sending-messages

```
// In main process.
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
    if(arg === 'ping')
        event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
    else
        event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'unrecognized arg');
})

// In renderer process (web page).
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
function callAgent(args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', args)
        ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, result) => {
            resolve(result);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually you define a new callback on every call, isn't it may cause to memory leak?

Comment: @Anatoly I agree, a good solution would be using removeListener with asynchronous-reply in the ipcRenderer asynchronous-reply callback I guess.

Comment: ipcRenderer.on is not compatible with contextBridge unfortunately...

Comment: Just use `ipcRenderer.once()` and switch the order - first `ipcRenderer.once()` then `ipcRenderer.send()`.