# What is the difference between IPC send / on and invoke / handle in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

I see an article that invoke / handle is asynchronous, but it's possible to use the old send / on.
It is easy to return the return value. You do not need to specify webcontents when sending from Main to renderer. The benefits are understandable

https://medium.com/@nornagon/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31
I don't think the remote module written in this article is relevant to send / on

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`invoke` is new api to help ergonomics around existing `send` / `on` pair when try to invoke some fn to return values to the sender. You can achieve same thing via `send` if you prefer to use it, there's no functional differences.

Comment: Agreed, funcional I don't see differences; love `promises`; I like that `handle/invoke` uses promises so you can `async/await`. Also, it throws an error if you try to invoke a `handle` that doesn't exists. One scenario where I rather use `on/send` is to set timeouts.

Comment: @GregK lol, the code is in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62630044/688552

Comment: there is a major difference in the use case: with `.send` and `.on`, the renderer can receive data from the ipcMain channel invoked multiple times, as long as the main process is running. 
Use cases for .send+.on would be async updates over time of some parts in your application, such as a count down, data updates, progress bar, etc
Use case for .invoke would be for example get values from electron-settings, since `enableRemoteModule` will be deprecated soon.