# Send data from main to renderer (ReactJS), ElectronJS, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I am trying to send data from `main.js` to ReactJS component.

preload.ts:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  getData(channel: 'get-data') {

    ipcRenderer.send(channel);
  },

});
```

main.ts:

```
ipcMain.on('get-data', (event) => {
  event.reply('get-data', 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
});
```

and in the ReactJS component - App.tsx:

```
const Hello = () => {

  console.log(window.electron.getData('get-data'));
......
```

, but in the console, I am getting `undefined`.

How to send data from `main.ts` to renderer (a ReactJS component)?

Comment: I might try to dig up another Q (this is surely a dupe), but `send` does not synchronously return the reply. There is a sync alternative (`sendSync` and `e.returnValue = "kkkkk"`), but it's preferable generally to do this asyncly by having getData return a promise (`return ipcRenderer.invoke` and in main.js, `ipcMain.handle(`)

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148110/how-to-add-a-callback-to-ipc-renderer-send/62630044#62630044

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, but still only `return data` in main -> `ipcMain.handle` and return it in `preload` works:  `    const data = await ipcRenderer.invoke(channel);
    return data;`

Answer (score 0):

Using `arrow function`

Only your arrow functions are exposed to your renderer.

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  getData: (channel: 'get-data') => {
    ipcRenderer.send(channel);
  },
});
```